# How to compile in gfortran in case Sensitive mode?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Is it possible to compile a fortran 90/95 code in **gfortran** with **Case Sensitive**?
I searched the manuals, but couldn't find any flag or option I can give to gfortran to make it case sensitive.
I want to have variables in upper case and lower case to be different.

So, is it possible?

Comment: I understand why you'd want to do this - in equations, G and g (say) are different variables.  But FORTRAN is _defined_ by the standard to be case-insensitive.  If you do find a combination of compiler/flags that allows you to do this, you'll be writing code which is absolutely guaranteed to completely fail when used with other compilers.

Comment: If gfortran have a standard flag, then I can always use it. 
While coding in C, I had the habit of making all matrices Upper case and others lower case. I'm finding it very difficult to break that habit when i switched over to fortran from C..

Comment: ..unless your compiler stopped supporting it, or you moved to another platform where you have to use/support another compiler.   Different languages have different approaches; to get the most benefit from any of them, you have to adapt your techniques to the idioms of that lanaguage.   It's tedious and painful, sometimes, but there it is.

Comment: You can use whatever case conventions you wish in your code, e.g., arrays in upper case and scalers in lower case, as you have used in C. There is nothing wrong with that as a coding convention. You could use camel case for something else... But you can't have an array and a scaler of the same name, distinguished by case because that would violate the Fortran standard. Nor will the compiler catch case-typos for you, since they are considered equivalent. Others have already answered why a flag changing this would be a bad idea.

Comment: Just to add to what Jonathan and MSB have said, even in languages that are case-sensitive, while using case to indicate something about the variable is common (e.g., all caps for constants), having two different variables that differ _only_ by case is a recipe for confusion.

Comment: +1 for the previous comment, don't rely on case for differentiating variables, bad idea

Comment: The true question is: WHY has Fortran been defined to be case-insestive? So many wasted variable names! Seven eighth for a 3-letter word, fifteen sixteenth for 4-letter words. What a waste of combinations.

Answer (score 8):

There is no such flag or option. Of course, gfortran being free software, you're welcome to download the source code and create your own version with that particular feature.

In reality, I'd recommend to just follow the Fortran standard and forget the idea of case sensitivity when programming Fortran.

Comment: oh, okey. Thanks.. Breaking my programming habit, might be an easier option than editing gfortran :(