# gfortran case sensitive include files

Tags: linux, fortran, gfortran

I was trying to compile a program in linux using gfortran. The program have a lot of include files. It seems the include files have names with uppercase but they are lowercase in the source code. I had to rename all the files to have the proper case. Is there an option in the compiler to avoid this?

Comment: That is surprising. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436463/how-to-compile-in-gfortran-in-case-sensitive-mode) and [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/285064).

Comment: Rename is a good strategy, it will be easier to maintain in the future. Other quick fix: dump this data on case-insensitive filesystem, like `vfat` or `cifs`

Comment: @MicahElliott That is not surprising at all. Your links are irrelevant, the file names are in character strings and those are case sensitive. They are not variable names.

Comment: Don't try the compiler to be case sensitive. We, fortran-programmers are not habituated that way. So, when anyone else see your program, will have hard time, and will think foo=FOO.

Instead, rename. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253584/linux-rename-files-to-uppercase

Comment: My message may not have been clear; some of you got it but just in case. I am not trying to have code that is case sensitive. Is code that was written (mostly for Windows environment) and the include lines read like _include 'params.puf'_ but the file was named PARAMS.PUF. Compiled this in Windows did not give me any problems but in Linux it have issues because as @Vladimir F pointed out the character variable value 'MyVariable' is not equal to 'MYVARIABLE'

Comment: the question is clear. I run into this all the time with windows-developed code. It seems plausible there could in principle be a compiler flag to do a case-insensitive search for include files, but as far as it seems anyone here knows there is no such thing.   One fix may be to create a bunch of symbolic links..